# How to handle ng-click inside directive Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
.directive("feedList", function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    feeds: '=feedData'
                },
                templateUrl: 'jstemplates/feed-list.html',


                link: function(scope) {

                    angular.forEach(scope.feeds, function(value, key) {
                        if(value.who.fullname == " "){
                            scope.feeds[key].fullname = "email";
                        }
                          console.log(value.who.fullname);
                    });

                }
        }
    })
```

Inside my template there is an event: `ng-click="do()"`. How to handle this event in directive ot in parent controller?

Comment: You didn't define `$scope.do()` in your link function. What's the function supposed to do? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's your isolated scope directive, so pass the callback function and then call that function directly from template or from controller or link function.
[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uttampankajsingh/g3brja67/158/)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.testFunction = function(){
     alert("Called from isolated scope directive");
   };
});

app.directive("isolatedScopeDirective", function(){
    return{
        scope:{
         go:"&"
        },
        template : `<button ng-click='go()'>Test Button</button>`
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <isolated-scope-directive go="testFunction()"></isolated-scope-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share example?

Comment: Sure. Just wait for some time.